# z3 Solver: Getting different results using "parseSMTLIB2String" vs. rise4fun online tool

Tags: java, z3

I'm using z3 to develop a Java program, but when I test a very simple encoding using "parseSMTLIB2String" method vs. rise4fun online tool, I got different results.

Below is my encoding for the test:

```
(declare-const s Bool)
(assert (exists ((p Bool))(or (not s) p)))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

When I test it using rise4fun online tool, it gives me the result:

```
sat
(model
(define-fun s () Bool
false)
)
```

But when I try to use the "parseSMTLIB2String" method in Java, it gives me the following result:

```
sat
(define-fun s () Bool
true)
```

So I'm wondering why they gave me different results.
Am I using the "parseSMTLIB2String" method in the wrong way?

Below is my small test class in Java:

```
HashMap<String, String> cfg = new HashMap<String, String>();
cfg.put("model", "true");
@SuppressWarnings("resource")
Context ctx = new Context(cfg);

BoolExpr[] formula = ctx.parseSMTLIB2String("(declare-fun s () Bool)\n" + 
  "(assert (exists ((p Bool))(or (not s) p)))", null, null, null, null);

Solver s = ctx.mkSolver();
s.add(formula);

Status result = s.check();

if (result == Status.SATISFIABLE){  
  System.out.println("sat");
  Model m = s.getModel();
  System.out.println(m.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

rise4fun does not run the latest version of Z3; it's quite possible the it is rather old now. For the constraint `(exists ((p Bool))(or (not s) p))`, both `true` and `false` are correct solutions for `s`.

(Just FYI: `parseSMTLIB2String` only parses assertions in the input file, this is not exactly the same as running the command-line Z3 on an SMT2 file.)